# Kotlin javaClass<> missing dependency in latest Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**Toolchain**:

- Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2:

  Build #AI-171.4041253, built on May 24, 2017
  JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b736 x86_64
  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  Mac OS X 10.12.5
- Google SDK/Tools: I have downloaded the latest "all" (Android O, tools, libraries, etc. at least according to Android Studio SDK Manager).

**Problem**: `javaClass<>` is missing and Android Studio can't "import it".

**What I did**:

1. Create new Android project, target API 23 and told it to include a "basic activity".
2. Added the Gradle dependencies for ViewModel and Room taken from: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

These are the lines I added to my App Module's gradle file:

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"    
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

3. The Kotlin reference in the same Gradle is: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"` (I didn't add that one, came automatically)
4. I then created a simple Kotlin class called `MainViewModel`:

   import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
   class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {}
5. Then I went to my Activity and tried to do what this Google Documentation says: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

It's in Java but converted to Kotlin, *I think* it should look like:

`val mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(javaClass<MainViewModel>)`

The problem is that Android Studio is not finding javaClass and the fix (to press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>) doesn’t do anything.

[image: Android Studio screen shot]

#### What am I missing?

Comment: How about your Kotlin compiler settings?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm I don’t know what they are, but they are certainly the “defaults” for I haven’t touched anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to try to use the Java To Kotlin conversion. So I created a new Activity in Java, and wrote the above code as the java documentation states.

After the class was working, I did `Code -> Convert Java Class To Kotlin` in Android Studio, and the resulting Kotlin class had the following line:

`val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)`

This compiled perfectly. I will have to learn more about which one is correct, but this one may save you some time if you’re, like me, new to the language.